# Least degree polynomial and Newton's sum? $a_1^k + a_2 ^k + \ldots + a_n^k = k $ for $k=2,3,\ldots,n+1$.

Tags: summation

Let $ a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots , a_n $ be complex number satisfying $ \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^n a_j ^k= k $ where $ k =2,3,\ldots, n+1 $.

Prove (or disprove) that the least degree polynomial with integer coefficients that has a root $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^n a_j $ is $ n+1 $.

---

I've made up this question. I have shown that it is true for $n=1,2,3,4$. I'm not sure whether it holds for all positive integer $n$.